# Can't deploy a flask application to the web with AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-amplify

I've been doing backend programming for years but I've now decided to finally tackle frontend.  I've watched two tutorials on using AWS amplify and one thing I don't understand is that I can only get my app to run on my localhost when I type

flask run

or

python flask_app.py

I have my code published on Github and AWS amplify says that it successfully reads it. However I don't see why the app would deploy to my webpage when I never actually run the flask app.  I'm assuming that AWS amplify puts the code from github onto a Linux machine but don't I have to SSH into that machine and write: `python flask_app.py`?

I'm not receiving any error messages but my webpage is still blank and I'm guessing that that is because I see no reason why any of the files would be executed if they are just sitting there on some computer out there.  Also, should I be concerned about this? In both of the tutorials I have watched there is an additional check mark which says 'verified' but not in my case.

[image: aws amplify]

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "Help me be swank"

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return "I'm swank"



app.run(debug=1)
```

Comment: Can you also put your CI/CD code here?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a template page that can render the text. Create a 'templates' folder in your project directory and within that create 'template.html' with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Then within your Flask code, you can render the content to the 'template.html' page you have just created:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("template.html", message="Help me be swank") 

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template("template.html", message="I'm swank")

app.run(debug=1)
```

Make sure that the 'render_template' argument variable name is the same as what's in the curly brackets in the html